# Erlang: Functions work in shell but not in YAWS

Tags: erlang, yaws

My sole method of debugging (`io:format/2`) is not working in YAWS. I'm at a loss. My supervisor starts three processes: ETS Manager, YAWS Init, and Ratelimiter. This is successful. I can play around with the rate limiter in the shell... calling the same functions YAWS should be. The difference being the shell behaves as I would expect and I have no idea what is happening in YAWS.

I do know if I spam the command in shell: `ratelimiter:limit(IP)` it will return `true` eventually. I can execute the following and it will also return `true`: `ratelimiter:lockout(IP), ratelimiter:blacklist(IP)`. The limiter is a `gen_server`.

The functions do the following:

- `limit/1`: Check ETS table if counter > threshold; update counter. If counter > blacklist threshold make entry in mnesia table
- `blacklist/1`: Check mnesia table if entry exists; Yes: reset timer
- `lockout/1`: Immediately enters ID into mnesia table

In my `arg_rewrite_mod` module I'm doing some checks to ensure I'm getting the HTTP requests I expect, namely GET, POST, and HEAD. I thought this would be a nice place to also do the rate limiting. Do it as soon as possible in the web server's chain of events.

All the changes I've made to the `arg_rewrite` module seem to work except using "printf"s and the limiter. I'm new to the language so I'm not sure my mistake is obvious or not.

Skeleton of my `arg_rewrite_mod`:

```erlang
-module(arg_preproc).
-export([arg_rewrite/1]).

-include("limiter_def.hrl").
-include_lib("/usr/lib/yaws/include/yaws_api.hrl").


is_blacklisted(ID) ->
    case ratelimiter:blacklist(ID) of
    false ->    continue;
    true ->     throw(blacklist)
    end.

is_limited(ID) ->
    case ratelimiter:limit(ID) of
    false ->    continue;
    true ->     throw(limit)
    end.


arg_rewrite(A) ->
    Allow = ['GET','POST', 'HEAD'],

    try
        {IP, _} = A#arg.client_ip_port,

        ID = IP,
        is_blacklisted(ID),

io:format("~p ~p ~n",[ID, is_blacklisted(ID)]),         

        %% === Allow expected HTTP requests
        HttpReq = (A#arg.req)#http_request.method,

        case lists:member(HttpReq, Allow) of
            true ->
                {_,ReqTgt} = (A#arg.req)#http_request.path,
                PassThru = [".css",".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".js"],
                %% ... much more ...
            false ->
                is_limited(ID),
                throw(http_method_denied)
        end
    catch
        throw:blacklist -> %% Send back a 429;
        throw:limit -> %% Same but no Retry-After;
        throw:http_method_denied ->
        %%Only thrown experienced
            AllowedReq = string:join([atom_to_list(M) || M <- Allow], ","),
            A#arg{state=#rewrite_response{status=405,
                        headers=[{header, {"Allow", AllowedReq}},{header, {connection, "close"}}]
            }};
        Type:Reason -> {error, {unhandled,{Type, Reason}}}
    end.
```

I can spam `curl -I -X HEAD <<any page>>` as fast as I can in a bash shell and all I get is `HTTP 200`. The ETS table has zero entries as well. Using `PUT` I get a `HTTP 405` as intended. I can `ratelimiter:lockout({MY_IP})` and get the web page to load in my browser and a `HTTP 200` with `curl`.

I'm confused. Is it the way I started YAWS?

```erlang
start() ->
    os:putenv("YAWSHOME", ?HOMEPATH_YAWS),
    code:add_patha(?MODPATH_YAWS),

    ok = case (R = application:start(yaws)) of
        {error, {already_started, _}} -> ok;
        _ -> R
    end,

    {ok,self()}. %% Tell supervisor everything okay in a manner it expects.
```

I did this because I thought it would be "easier."

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether you're starting Yaws as a stand-alone web server or as an embedded web server within a larger application. If stand-alone, you can run Yaws with the `-i` command-line option to make it interactive, which can often be useful for debugging. If embedded, you should be following the [Yaws embedded startup documentation](http://yaws.hyber.org/embed.yaws) to make sure you're starting it correctly. Lastly, you should be using a `shaper` module for this functionality; see the [yaws.conf man page](http://yaws.hyber.org/yman.yaws?page=yaws.conf).

Comment: I had started to write out the code to launch it embedded and realized I'm just copying everything over from the conf file into code. I figured I would just cut that out. I will look into the shaper... also will see if I can do anything with my datastore in a webpage.

Comment: Your nudge was of great help. Simply adding `application:set_env(yaws,embedded,true)` solved the problem. The amount of time spent on this prior to posting is large. Otherwise I wouldn't ask. Thank you for helping.

Comment: Glad it's resolved.

Comment: FYI I created a `#yaws` channel on the [Erlang Slack site](https://erlanger.slack.com/), so if you have further questions about `shaper` that are difficult to frame for this forum, or questions about any other aspect of Yaws, feel free to join there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting Yaws as part of another application, it's important to use its [embedding support](http://yaws.hyber.org/embed.yaws). One important thing the Yaws embedding startup code does is set the application environment variable `embedded` to `true`:

```
application:set_env(yaws, embedded, true),
```

Yaws checks this variable in several of its code paths, especially during initialization, in order to avoid assuming that it's running as a stand-alone daemon process.

Regarding rate limiting, rather than using an arg rewriter, you might consider using a [shaper](https://github.com/klacke/yaws/blob/master/src/yaws_shaper.erl). The `yaws_shaper` module provides a behavior that expects its callback module to implement two functions:

- `check/1`: `yaws_shaper` calls this to allow the callback module to decide whether to allow the request from the client. It passes client host information as the callback argument. Your shaper callback module returns either the atom `allow` to allow the request to proceed, or the tuple `{deny, Status, Message}` where `Status` is an HTTP status code to return to the client, such as 429 to indicate the client is making too many requests, and `Message` is any extra HTML to be returned to the client. (It might be nice if `Message` could include a reply header such as `Retry-After` as well; this is something I'll consider adding to Yaws.)
- `update/3`: `yaws_shaper` calls this when the response for a client is ready to be returned. The first argument is the client host information, the second argument is the number of "hits" (the value 1 for each request), and the third argument is the number of bytes being delivered in response to the client's request. Your shaper callback module can return `ok` from `update/3` (Yaws does not use the return value).

A shaper can use this framework to track how many requests each client is making and how much data Yaws is delivering to each client, and use that information to limit or deny particular clients.

And finally, while "printf debugging" works, it's less than ideal especially in Erlang, which has built-in tracing. You should consider learning the [`dbg` module](https://erlang.org/doc/man/dbg.html) so you can trace any function you want, see who called it, see what arguments are being passed to it, see what it returns, etc.